# How to show sin is continuous at $x \in (-1/2, 1/2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to show the continuity of the sin function from $x_0 \in (-1/2, 1/2)$. My professor asked 2 parts, and I am stuck on the first part:

Given $\epsilon > 0$, show that there exists N such that for all $x_0 \in (-1/2, 1/2)$,

$$|\sum_{n > N}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Currently, this is what I have:

We note that $(2n + 1)! \geq 1$ and $|x|^{2n + 1} \leq 2^{-(2n+1)}$. This implies that

$$|\sum_{n > N}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}| \leq \sum_{n > N}^\infty 2^{-(2n+1)}$$

Hence, we want to find when $\sum_{n > N}^\infty 2^{-(2n+1)} < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. We see that

$$\sum_{n > N}^\infty 2^{-(2n+1)}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n > N}^\infty (\frac{1}{4})^n = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (\frac{1}{4})^n - \sum_{n = 0}^N (\frac{1}{4})^n \bigg) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{2 - (-1/4)^n + 4}{3}\bigg)$$.

Thus, we want to check $\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{2 - (-1/4)^n + 4}{3}\bigg) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Doing the algebra, **Here's where im stuck on**

$$(-\frac{1}{4})^n < -3\epsilon - 2$$

Am I allowed to take the log and isolate the n? (I want to isolate n because we can choose N greater than n and the problem would be solved) We haven't rigorously defined log yet, which is why I'm apprehensive of taking the log. Also, I'm not sure if I am on the right track to showing what they want me to show, since I haven't included $x_0$ anywhere. I would appreciate any pointers.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but here's a hint on a straightforward way to approach the inequality: $$|\sum_{n > N}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x_0^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}| \leq |\sum_{n > N}^\infty \frac{x_0^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}|$$

Comment: Another hint: pay attention to values $x_0$ can take. This allows you to easily turn the above inequalities into something much easier to work with